# Building a re-usable class library in C#

Tags: c#, class, dll

I have a class library I've built for a coworker to use that, after giving her the .dll file, I cannot get to work. The name of the .dll file is "BatchDashboard." The name of the namespace is "BatchDashboard," and the name of the class (there is only one) is "BatchDashboard." Is it a problem to have all three similarly named? Visual Studio is able to add the reference just fine. However, this statement:

```
using BatchDashboard;
```

spits out the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'BatchDashboard' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Likewise, I cannot instantiate a new 'BatchDashboard' object.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thx!

EDIT

I have tried adding the reference to another test project on my computer and receive the same results.

SECOND EDIT

Changing the access modifier to public for the "BatchDashboard" class fixed the issue with the using statement. However, when I try to instantiate an object like so:

```
BatchDashboard batch = new BatchDashboard();
```

I got the following error:

```
'BatchDashboard' is a namespace but is used like a 'type'
```

It was necessary for me to have different class and namespace names to work. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps your project targets a later version of the .NET Framework than your coworker's does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I know what problem you have. When you created your class file, you probably didn't change access to your class to "public". In .Net, unless you have public members in the assembly, the namespace wouldn't be found in "using" directive.
Basically, check if the class you have is a "public class"

Comment: Also, as practice, you should never name your objects with same names as namespaces. Just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my best guesses:

1. You compiled it against the wrong CPU target
2. You have a dependency on a Runtime library that should be added as a reference to the 
   project also.

Comment: I think this might be it. However, the reference I'm thinking of is a typical .Net one: System.Data & System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: If you have ever used the DataContractJsonSerializer class, it has a dependency, but VS never tells you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- The library is added as reference to the project
- That library is in a equal or prior .NET version compared to your project's .NET version.